# Is it possible to sum values within log lines in Loki / Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

If I have 2 log lines, e.g:

```
01/02/2022 - my log line - arbitrary number: 40
02/02/2022 - another log line - arbitrary number: 60
```

Within Grafana (or loki) is it possible to add together the 'arbitrary numbers' and give me an output of 100?

The use case is that I have multiple labels, each label has thousands of log lines. I want to create a dashboard which displays a sum of 'arbitrary numbers' per label

From what I've seen in the docs (https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/) I get the feeling loki / grafana can only be used for metadata of the log stream, and not manipulating the log values themselves?